# fcm getToken is going into infinite loop

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, push-notification

I am making ionic cordova app with push notification using FCM. but when i am calling getToken() in fcm.ts provider it is going into loop.

this is the code.

```
async getToken() {
console.log("in getToken");
let token;

if (this.platform.is('android')) {
  console.log("in android");
  token = await this.firebaseNative.getToken();
  console.log("token"+token);
}

if (this.platform.is('ios')) {
  token = await this.firebaseNative.getToken();
  await this.firebaseNative.grantPermission();
}
```

console log keeps writing these logs after calling this.

```
in get Token
in android
in get Token
in android
```

here is the code where I am calling this. it is in constructor of home.ts

```
constructor(private storage: Storage, public nav: NavController, public popoverCtrl: PopoverController, 
public commonSerivce: CommonService, private modalCtrl: ModalController, 
private actionSheetCtrl: ActionSheetController, public camera: Camera, 
public imagePicker: ImagePicker,  public toastCtrl: ToastController, public platform: Platform, 
public loadingCtrl: LoadingController,fcm: FcmProvider,public firebaseNative: Firebase) {
  platform.registerBackButtonAction(() => {
    this.selectedImages = [];
  },1);
  fcm.getToken();
  // Listen to incoming messages
  fcm.listenToNotifications().pipe(
    tap(msg => {
      // show a toast
      console.log(msg);
       const toast = toastCtrl.create({
        message:  msg["body"],
        duration: 3000
      });
      toast.present(); 
    })
  ).subscribe();
}
```

i am following this tutorial.
[Independent Notification service using Ionic, Node & FCM](https://medium.com/hirewithparam/independent-notification-service-using-ionic-node-fcm-5cdde219480a)

Comment: You need to share the code that calls the method you shown. The code you shared so far is not indicating any issues

Comment: @SergeyRudenko I have edited the question. as per your request.